# Master-detail relationship query all children

Tags: visualforce, query, master-detail

The Master object Custom_Opportunity__c have a master-detail relationship on Product__c. Normally there are many Product__c records under one Custom_Opportunity__c record. Every time I use Custom_Opportunity__c.Product__r in my VF page, it shows the newest record.

Is there a way for me to query all the children under this Custom_Opportunity__c and let the user to choose which child they want to work on?
In the object layout page, all the children can be seen. However, now I want to show them in a VF page. And my major issue here is to get all children records once together.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to query all products based on your custom opportunity id. For example:

```
SELECT Id FROM Product__c WHERE Custom_Opportunity__c = :yourCustomOpportunityId
```

This will return you all products that are children of the given custom opportunity

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make parent-child SOQL in controller at the time of page load (constructor)

```
ex: Custom_Opportunity__c co = [Select id,(select id, fields__c from Product__r) form Custom_Opportunity__c where id=: oppid];
```

> Make sure that "Product__r" is the child relationship name.

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: The child relationship name is Loan_Product__r. I tried the SOQL like

Comment: Select id,(select id, fields__c from Loan_Product__r) from Custom_Opportunity__c where id= 'a0EN0000005oBXj'

Comment: It says Didn't understand relationship 'Loan_Product__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: Please go to the Loan Object. Go the relationship field that links with Opportunity. Click on the field  and it will show a label "Child relationship name". The Child relationship is differ from the field API name. Also. append "__r" in the child relationship name present in the field. For ex: if it is load_products then use "loan_products__r" in the SOQL

Comment: You can try `select id, field__c from Loan_Product__c where Custom_Opportunity__c = 'a0EN0000005oBXj'` `Custom_Opportunity__c` in this case would be the field on Loan_Product__c that stores master record reference